# Best way to calculate the number of unique orderings of a multiset

Tags: c, math

I'm looking for a way to calculate the following better.
The problem is I can't figure out the name for this type of combination.
First I thought if I had 3 "a"s and 2 "b"s,
then I could put b in a+1 positions _a_a_a_ each time, for (a+1)^b times, but the choice order of positions 0 and then 1 or 1 and then 0 are the same: i.e. "baba".

I've figured out this recursive way to calculate it.

```
/* find all permutations of a non unique sequence of 0s and 1s
... "a"s and "b"s etc... */
/* e.g. how many ways to arange 4 apples and 3 oranges, 35 */

int *perms(int a, int b){
    static int total = 0;
    if(!a && !b){
        total++;
        return 0;
    }
    if(a > 0){
        perms(a-1,b);
    }
    if(b > 0){
        perms(a,b-1);
    }
    return &total;
}
```

I have a strong feeling that I can do much, much better.

Comment: LMGTFY: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets

Comment: So I should have been looking for "permutations of multisets" and my answer, in this case,  is (a+b)! / (a! * b!) . Thanks!

Comment: Donald Knuth and "The Art of Computer Programming" is your jam.  larsmans had it.

Comment: @mbowden: now that you have found your answer, feel free to post it as an answer to your question. This will help others, and will get this question out of the “unanswered” queue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, given by larsmans in the comments, is (a+b)! / (a! * b!) or

```
factorial(a + b) / (factorial(a) * factorial(b))
```